# Count numbers of subdirectories and files with special conditions in Python

Tags: python, count, operating-system, os.walk, listdir

I have a folder `test` from which I want count the numbers of `projects`,  `buildings` and `txt_files` by the following rule.

For the number of `projects`, it simply equals to the number of subfolders of the first layer subdirectories. For the number of `buildings`, it equals to the numbers of the first layer of subdirectories if it does not have the second layer of subdirectories, otherwise, count the second layer of subdirectories.

```
├─a
│  ├─a1
│  ├─a2
│  └─a3
│      ├─a3_1.txt
│      ├─a3_2.geojson
│      └─a3_3.txt
├─b
│  ├─b1
│  ├─b2
│  ├─b3
│  └─b4
├─c
│  ├─c1
│  ├─c2
│  └─c3
├─d
└─123.txt
```

For the following example structures: `num_projects` is `4` which contains the first layer subfolders: `a, b, c, d`; while `num_buildings` is `11`, which contains subdirectories: `a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, b4, c1, c2, c3 and d`; and `num_txt` is `3`.

My solution so far:

```
import os

path = os.getcwd()

num_projects = 0 
num_buildings = 0 
num_txt = 0 

for subdirs in os.listdir(path):
    num_projects += 1    

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for dirname in dirnames:
        num_buildings += 1
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename[-4:] == ".txt":
            num_txt += 1

print("Number of projects is %d, number of buildings is %d, number of txt files is %d." %(num_projects, num_buildings, num_txt))
```

Output:

```
Number of projects is 5, number of buildings is 17, number of txt files is 3.
```

The `num_projects` and `num_buildings` are wrong. How could I make it correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) is a generator and should be able to handle many directories (and subdirectories) without worrying about memory.

It's not elegant but try this:

```
import os

projects = 0
buildings = 0
txt_files = 0

path = os.getcwd()

for root, directories, files in os.walk(path):
    if root == path:
        projects = len(directories)
        for sub_dir in directories:
            full_dir = os.path.join(root, sub_dir)
            for root_, directories_, files_ in os.walk(full_dir):
                if root_ == full_dir:
                    if directories_ == []:
                        buildings += 1
                    else:
                        buildings += (len(directories_))

    for i in files:
        if i.endswith('.txt'):
            txt_files += 1

print("There are {} projects, {} buildings and {} text files".format(projects, buildings, txt_files))
```

Comment: One more question, what does the code `if root == path` and `if root_ == full_dir` mean in your solution?

Comment: Oh, ```os.walk()``` loops through the entire folder structure of the path passed to it, *starting from that path itself*. ```if root == path``` and ```if root_ == full_dir``` essentially check if the path being checked (the current path in ```os.walk()```) is the very path itself. So, given your test folder structure above, the ```if root == path``` checks that ```os.walk()``` is currently in the ```test``` folder, i.e. containing the ```a, b, c, d``` folders. Then for each sub directory in `test`, say a, ```if root_ == full_dir``` checks that ```os.walk()``` is in the ```a``` folder itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have two distinct issues here:

Issue #1 (`num_projects`): `os.listdir()` list ALL entries in the path - not only directories.

> How to make it correct?

Well, quite simply, test if the entry is a file or directory before increasing your counter.

Issues #2 (`num_buildings`):

your spec :

> it equals to the numbers of the first layer of subdirectories if it does not have the second layer of subdirectories, otherwise, count the second layer of subdirectories.

is actually NOT implemented AT ALL in your code - you just count all directories and subdirectories.

> How to make it correct?

Trying to implement the specs could be a good starting point... Note that `os.walk()` might not be the best solution here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I haven't mastered Python very well yet but I'll try my best.